# Why is my matrix being filled with NAs, not the output of the loop?

Tags: r, loops

I am looking to fill matrix tab with the output of the look (variable ma), however instead it is filling the matrix with NAs

```
MA<-data.matrix(my_data)
MA2=MA[-247,-8]
tab<-matrix(ncol=2,nrow=253)
ma4<-matrix(ncol=1,nrow=253)
tab[,1]<-MA2[,1]
for (n in 1:248) {
  y<-MA2[c(n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,n+5),5]
  z<-sum(y)
  mav<-z/5
  tab[[n,2]]<-mav
  n<-n+1
}
```

link to data is here https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/LLOY.L/history?p=LLOY.L

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data, please?

Comment: I have downloaded an read the data and run your code. `tab` is not full of NA but mostly filled with numbers. Please provide code for reading the data and specifdy the problem.

Comment: https://imgur.com/rsQp2tI

Comment: the second column of tab is filled with NA's, I would like it to be filled with mav ouputs of the loop

Comment: Not when I do it. `> head(tab[,2])
[1] 101.6  95.6 103.6 112.4 116.4 127.0`

Comment: apologies I am new to r, is this head(tab[,2]) run outside the loop?

Comment: i am getting the error message `NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: I need more room to explain what I did so I made it an answer. See below how your code worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I cannot explain this in comments, thus here.

I downloaded the data, used `setwd()` to set the working directory to the directory with the file. Then

```
my_data <- read.csv("LLOY.L.csv")
```

Testing if it worked:

```
> str(my_data)
'data.frame':   254 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Date     : Factor w/ 254 levels "2019-02-06","2019-02-07",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Open     : Factor w/ 220 levels "48.349998","48.580002",..: 90 107 69 73 84 98 99 70 108 110 ...
 $ High     : Factor w/ 229 levels "49.000000","49.230000",..: 96 92 68 73 82 94 85 111 108 117 ...
 $ Low      : Factor w/ 235 levels "48.155998","48.230999",..: 110 89 77 82 107 112 97 90 125 122 ...
 $ Close    : Factor w/ 221 levels "48.580002","48.680000",..: 104 68 61 86 97 92 74 108 105 106 ...
 $ Adj.Close: Factor w/ 235 levels "48.580002","48.680000",..: 58 47 44 52 55 53 50 61 59 60 ...
 $ Volume   : Factor w/ 254 levels "101608167","102059589",..: 12 62 43 26 57 13 253 72 240 23 ...
```

Yes, the data are read. However, the numbers are read als factors. At closer inspection of the data there is a "null" value, which is probably an `NA` thus we read the data as

my_data <- read.csv("LLOY.L.csv", na.strings="null")

Now numeric values are numeric. Now your code from the question.

```
MA<-data.matrix(my_data)
MA2=MA[-247,-8]
tab<-matrix(ncol=2,nrow=253)
ma4<-matrix(ncol=1,nrow=253)
tab[,1]<-MA2[,1]
for (n in 1:248) {
  y<-MA2[c(n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,n+5),5]
  z<-sum(y)
  mav<-z/5
  tab[[n,2]]<-mav
  n<-n+1
}
```

Runs without a warning or an error. Now let's see, what happend to `tab`:

```
summary(tab)
```

results in

```
> summary(tab)
       V1            V2       
 Min.   :  1   Min.   :58.82  
 1st Qu.: 64   1st Qu.:68.43  
 Median :127   Median :70.11  
 Mean   :127   Mean   :70.09  
 3rd Qu.:190   3rd Qu.:74.65  
 Max.   :254   Max.   :78.77  
               NA's   :11
```

As you can see, there are only 11 `NA` in the second column and enough numbers to compute a summary.

```
> head(tab)
     [,1]   [,2]
[1,]    1 69.176
[2,]    2 69.004
[3,]    3 69.252
[4,]    4 69.540
[5,]    5 69.670
[6,]    6 70.304
```